# Get controller name from httpcontext dotnet 6

Tags: c#, .net

I simply want to fetch controller name in a middleware. There are a bunch of answers which use `RequestContext` or `RouteData` like below:

```
string controllerName = context.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
```

I've tried this but it always returns null for me, what is the way to do this in .NET 6?

**Update:** .NET Version is 6.0.100-rc.1.21458.32

My Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "RMS.Admin.Api", Version = "v1" });
});

builder.Services.AddCoreServices(configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "RMS.Admin.Api v1"));
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.



app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseElmah();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseAuditLogMiddleware();

app.UseErrorLoggingMiddleware();

app.Run();
```

Middleware's invoke method:

```
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IUserContext userContext, IAuditLogContract auditLogContract)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(httpContext.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>());
            auditLogContract.Add(new AuditLog
            {
                LoginStatus = (userContext.Id == "") ? false : true,
                Controller = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"]?.ToString(),
// More code here
            });

            await this.next(httpContext);
        }
```

Comment: Do us a favor and be so kind to paste in your program.cs / Startup.cs code (where your middleware is set up), so we can reproduce your problem. Might also be a good idea to run a `dotnet --version` so we can operate from the same build, if we try to retrace your steps.

Comment: Now we need the code to your middleware please. I guess its Audit and / ErrorLogMiddleware,  but we need to be sure.

Comment: @Marco added the Invoke method

Answer (score 4):

I've just tested this and it definitely works under .Net 6. Be aware that middleware is order dependant and if your middleware is called before `app.UseRouting()`, your RouteValues will be null.

Application code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
//if you need your route values this is the earliest point you can inject your middleware into the pipeline. 

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
   var controller = context.Request.RouteValues["controller"]?.ToString();

   await next();
});

app.Run();
```

tested on

```
➜ dotnet --version
6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14
```

Comment: I'm passing an `HttpContext` in my middleware and want to get controller inside the `Invoke` method. Why do I need app.Use()?

Comment: The code in Use is a Middleware, just not a single class. You can write the same in the Middleware class

Comment: you don't need to use this. I was just being lazy and inlined the middleware instead of creating a bespoke class for it.

Comment: I just checked Program.cs of the project and we're not using app.UseRouting anywhere. Maybe thats why I'm getting null, any solutions?

Comment: What is your template based off of? MVC, Web Api or Razor Pages?

Comment: Web API, I believe

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer from Marco the following solution works too. This is if you need more information on the type of the controller, not just the name, e.g. the `TypeInfo` of the controller class, the `MethodInfo` of the called action, ....

```
app.Use(async (e, next) =>
{
    var controllerActionDescriptor = e.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
    await next();
});
```

**NOTE** It is important that this code is placed after `app.UseRouting` otherwise `GetEndpoint()` returns `null`;